# Is it possible to read java local variables and operand stack using ASM?

Tags: java, instrumentation, callstack, java-bytecode-asm

Like eclipse debugger does, is it possible to read java local variables and operand stack using ASM/-javaagent library? I am not sure if eclipse uses a java agent or native agent, I think it uses native agent.

I would like read variables and their values in all frames of the stack when exception occurs. I know it can be done using -agentlib/-agentpath native library using JVMTI. However I would like to know if that is possible using ASM or java agent library?

Comment: "Agents can be written in any native language that supports C language calling conventions and C or C++ definitions." from [Oracle's JVMTI introduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#writingAgents). May or may not be outdated.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, Thanks for the response. True. I can write a native library in C using JVMTI. Actually I have written one. However I would like to know if same thing can achieved using ASM? I already have one java agent developed using ASM and having another native agent using JVMTI creates additional dependency. Hence I would like to do this as well in the same java agent using ASM, if possible.

Comment: As C is translated to machine code, just like assembly is, you can. Of course you must adhere to the ABI and you don't have the types so you must access the fields of the structs by adding offset to their base pointers. Probably, disassembly a test agent would shed some light.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom, Sorry. I am actually referring to ObjectWeb ASM, a Java library for bytecode modification/instrumentation and analysis.

Comment: Then this was mistagged.  `[assembly]` is for native CPU asm/machine code.  `[java-bytecode-asm]` is for the library you're using.

Comment: ASM is a bytecode processing library. It has nothing to do with processing runtime values on the stack. Java Agents can use the [`Instrumentation` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) and it’s easy to see that it doesn’t provide the same features as JVMTI. Eclipse’s debugging features are another thing, as unlike an Agent, Eclipse runs in a different JVM than the inspected application.